# How do I convert a list represented as a string to a list?

Tags: java, android, json

I am building an Android application which reads from `themoviedb.org.`

What I am trying to do is have the user enter a movie title and use that title to find its id.

When I run the query to search for movies, I get a response like:

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "poster_path": "aaaaa.jpg",
            "id": "11",
            "description": "MovieDescription"
        },
        {
            "poster_path": "bbbbb.jpg",
            "id": "12",
            "description": "MovieDescription2"
        },
        {
            "poster_path": "ccccc.jpg",
            "id": "13",
            "description": "MovieDescription"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using the Maven JSON library, I can fetch the `results` key as a string using `json.get("results")`.

returning:

```
[
    {
        "poster_path": "aaaaa.jpg",
        "id": "11",
        "description": "MovieDescription"
    },
    {
        "poster_path": "bbbbb.jpg",
        "id": "12",
        "description": "MovieDescription2"
    },
    {
        "poster_path": "ccccc.jpg",
        "id": "13",
        "description": "MovieDescription"
    }
]
```

But I want to convert the first of these results to another `JSONObject` so that I can get the movie's id from the first result.

I'm thinking that the way to do this is to convert the `results` value to a list of `JSONObject` and then use the `json.get("id")` method on the first object in the list. But I do not know how to do this conversion.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The "results" are just a JSON array, you'll need convert the `JSONObject` to a "JSON Array" object (sorry, don't have the API available) which should then allow you to access the individual methods

Comment: Oh, I guess that makes it much easier, thanks! I just created a new JSONObject from the first item in the JSONArray using JSONArray.get(0). Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSONObject.getJSONArray` to get the result directly as a JSON Array:

```
JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray("results") // Get results as JSON Array
JSONObject first = results.getJSONObject(0) // Get first object as JSON Object
```

See: [JSONObject#getJSONArray(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray(java.lang.String))

Comment: @kyrolen you're welcome, would be great if you accept my answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers